# Spring Tool Suite: Cannot Execute a Simple Demo because of Spring Boot Build Path ERROR

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

The Error is as follows:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext. Fix the
>   build path then try building this project springbootdemo      Unknown Java
>   Problem

**2 ERROR items:**

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type The type
>   org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files MainActivity.java   /springbootdemo/src/main/java/springbootdemo    line
>   10    Java Problem

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainActivity {

    public MainActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this is where the ERROR happens beginning at 
        //  "SpringApplication.run(MainActivity.class, args);"
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MainActivity.class, args);

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>labs.noogui.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springboot course-api</name>

<parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>  

</project>
```

**Project Structure:**

[image]

[image]

```
 **Spring Tool Suite** 

Version: 3.9.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201804120921
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)
```

I'm following [the Spring Boot tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w1j7E_9Xj0) from Edureka!

How do I fix this build path error? I mean, this is like a spring boot hello world and I'm already running into errors?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ApplicationContext` from `org.apache.catalina.core`.

Import and use this `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` instead.

Your IDE is showing compile errors. Error message should probably lead you to the right direction.

Comment: nope man. doesnt fix it. thanks tho. im so frustrated right now

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "doesn't fix it". any other error messages after you applied the fix?

Comment: org.springframework.boot.context.ApplicationContext is not a valid import - "This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached source."

Comment: my bad, there is a typo, the import should not contain "boot", now it should work.

Comment: It can't read "import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;" .. did I miss a dependency import in my pom.xml?

Comment: Your current pom.xml should work. Try clean and re-import the dependencies, i think eclipse has a quick way to do that with maven.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code,

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainActivity {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(MainActivity.class, args);

 }
}
```

or if you want to use ApplicationContext to start the application then use below line but both are almost same.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainActivity {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MainActivity.class, args);

 }
}
```

Comment: It can't read "import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;" .. did I miss a dependency import in my pom.xml?

Comment: try to clean and update your maven project. Also if you imported any other wrong class delete and import the right ones

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the folks who tried to help but I found out that the problem is with maven's 'corrupted' repository (again). So as always, deleting the .m2/repository and updating your maven project resolves the issue.

Related post in this [github forum](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/170). This is a recurring issue with maven.